# how to do formatting of a file in unix

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a file `file.txt`. which have below three records.

```
<ResultDescxmlns="http://www.mpaet.com/boe/interface/common">Operation successful.
220095
9251000014
```

Now my desired format should be as below.

```
9251000014|220095|Operation successful
```

Comment: the real file, does it have more records like this, or only one record ?

Comment: Since the file appears to be a mix of different formatting conventions, it would be helpful if you stated what the format was (although the example is useful too). Further writing a script to rearrange one file is a massive overkill - do you have multiple input files you want to merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
sed 's/^<[^>]*>//g' file.txt | tr '\012' '|' | awk -F'|' '{OFS=FS; print $3,$2,$1}'
9251000014|220095|Operation successful.
```

If you want to strip the trailing `.` you could do that either with the `sed` or the `awk` (no need for both). Here's a drop-in solution with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^<[^>]*>//g' -e 's/\.$//' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using "perl" and Regular Expression

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<ResultDescxmlns=.*?>([^\n]*).([^\n]*).([^\n]*)/\3|\2|\1/gs' file.txt
```

This will extract the 3 lines following the `ResultDescxmlns` tag and rearrange them into the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

`sed`:

```
sed -rn 's/<ResultDescxmlns.*>(.*)/\1/;N;N;s/\n/ /g;s/([^.]*). ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*)/\3|\2|\1/p'
```

`s/.*ResultDescxmlns.*>(.*)/\1/` : find the match for line `.*ResultDescxmlns.*>(.*)` get string after `>` in `\1`

`N;N;`:  Add next 2 lines to to the current line

`s/\n/ /g`: replace newline by space

`s/([^.]*). ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*)/\3|\2|\1/p` : match regex and rearrange the order to get desired output

Answer (score 0):

This works on your data. Perhaps you can give more info on what you need.

```
awk -F'>' '/ResultDescxmlns/{ a = $2; getline b; getline c; printf "%s|%s|%s\n",c,b,a }' <file.txt
```

When it matches a word in a line, it splits the line on the char `>`, and puts field 2 in variable a. It calls `getline` to read the next line in variable b, and again c. It prints these variables with the wanted format in the order given. (I left the final `.` in variable a. You can remove it with `sub(/\./,"",a);`).

Answer (score 0):

If the file.txt has only 3 lines, this works as well :

```
l3=$(tail -1 file.txt)
l2=$(tail -2 file.txt | head -1)
l1=$(tail -3 file.txt | head -1 | cut -d">" -f2)
echo $l3"|"$l2"|"$l1
```

Comment: Consider using `l2=$(sed -n '2{p;q}' file.txt)` instead of `l2=$(tail -2 file.txt | head -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
awk -F"[>\n]" -v RS="" '{print $4"|"$3"|"$2}'
```